# Javascript: Move row in google spreadsheet if column contains any date (1/2/2015)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to move an entire row if a date is entered into column 6. The code works when I try to move a specific text, but if i try to use any date range, nothing happens. I have a feeling that the way that i'm expressing my IF statement is incorrect. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
function onEdit(event) {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
var d =  Date(month, day, year);
// BEGINNING OF MAIN
if(s.getName() == "UNITS ON ORDER" && r.getColumn() == 6 && r.getDate() == d ) {
var row = r.getRow();
var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("UNITS ON CONSIGNMENT");
var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
s.deleteRow(row);
}
}
```

Comment: Do you want to check if value in 'r' is a certain date or is within a certain date range or simply is a date ?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to move rows you when a date is entered, maybe you can try to use Date.parse() ?
Maybe something like this, will do the trick ?

```
function onEdit(event) {

var ss = event.source;
var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
var r = event.range; 
if (s.getName() == "UNITS ON ORDER" && r.columnStart == 6 && !isNaN(Date.parse(r.getValue()))) {
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    ss.getSheetByName("UNITS ON CONSIGNMENT")
        .appendRow(s.getRange(r.rowStart, 1, 1, numColumns)
            .getValues()[0])
    s.deleteRow(r.rowStart);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested your guy's solutions, yet. But what I did to get around it, in the column there is a TBD text field, and i set the IF statement to !=... because the person is entering in the date, and it isn't coming from a machine.